# How do I setup editors on linux?

Tags: text-editor

I downloaded text editors (komodo, eclipse, sublime text, and medit).
I opened the dash home but, they are in tar.gz format and are opening in archive managers as folders. How do I open them?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to install them. In this post you will find a great post with plenty documentation: http://askubuntu.com/q/25961/62483

Comment: Medit is available from the Software Center. No need to download a `tar.gz` for medit.

Comment: Priority for installing software: distribution packages -> package repositories maintained by original application developers -> compiling from source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find a README or a INSTALL file in these folders with instructions on how to install. Most likely, they are **1. ./configure 2. make 3. make install** .
The easier option is to execute **sudo apt-get install vim** in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use aptitude? Open up a terminal and type:

```
 sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

The .tar.gz files are source code. If you extract them, they will contain installation instructions.

Comment: He wants an editor not an IDE.

Comment: @Jay He said he wanted to install Eclipse... Is there an editor called Eclipse?

Comment: sorry for not specifying but eclipse is an IDE. Thanks for your help though.